# No rows are being inserted into DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, class, authentication, datatable

Trying to create a login function. I created a class which will have the functionality to fill a  datatable from an sql query but it is not working. No errors just no data inserting.

Here is my login function class:

```
namespace GymCalculator
{
    public class LoginFunction
    {
        public DataTable Login (string username, string pword)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionHelper.CnnVal("GymDB"))) {
                string query = ("Select * from [USER] where username = '{username}'  and password = '{pword}'");
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dtbl);
                return dtbl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code to call the class and the function:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var LoginFunction = new LoginFunction();
        var DataTable = new DataTable();

        DataTable = LoginFunction.Login(Usernametxt.Text, Passwordtxt.Text);
        if (DataTable.Rows.Count == 1) {
            CalculatorMain calculatorMain = new CalculatorMain();
            this.Hide();
            calculatorMain.Show();
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("You entered the wrong username or password");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: string query = ("Select * // This should be:  string query = ($"Select *  // The $ indicated 'string interpolation' // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: That is correct! What does the $ mean?

Comment: ** noted edited answer with link to Microsoft for full explanation. **

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use string interpolation to insert the user name and password text directly into the sql query. While @Epistaxis comment will fix the issue with inserting the strings I strongly suggest the use of query parameters to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @Andrew Would you use a stored procedure for a query so simple?

Comment: Didn't know about the 5 minute comment edit limit...   There is no need to use a stored procedure to use parameterize the query.  Using SqlCommand object, which looks like it's hidden in ConnectionHelper, you might do something like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pword);`  and the query would change to `Select * from [USER] where username = @username  and password = @password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final working code... I ended up using a stored procedure.

```
{
public class LoginFunction
{
    public DataTable Login (string username, string pword)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionHelper.CnnVal("GymDB")))

        {


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoginUser", connection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", pword);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);
            return dtbl;



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully this is for educational purposes. Passwords should not be plain text. It's not just insecure for your application, it puts your users at risk in general because people tend to use the same passwords on multiple systems.

Comment: Just practicing :)